# Como conjugar verbos que exprimem fenômenos da natureza?

Tags: conjugações, verbos-defectivos

Minha dúvida é sobre quais conjugações são possíveis para verbos que exprimem fenômenos da natureza, tais como "chover" e "trovejar". Alguém sabe?

É sabido que estes são defectivos, mas existe uma regra geral sobre como conjugá-los?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sobre este assunto dizem Ceslo Cunha e Lindley Cintra na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, (Lisboa, 1984, p. 554-5):

> Muitas vezes é a própria ideia expressa pelo verbo que não pode aplicar-se a determinadas pessoas. Assim, no seu significado próprio, verbos que exprimem fenómenos da natureza, como *chover, trovejar, ventar*, só aparecem na 3.ª pessoa do singular.

Indicam depois uma lista mais completa:

> alvorecer, amanhecer, anoitecer, chover, chuviscar, estiar, nevar, orvalhar, relampejar, saraivar, trovejar, ventar.

Agora, isto é no significado próprio. Alguns destes verbos podem ser usado em sentido figurado, admitindo aí conjugações noutras pessoas. Por exemplo, o [Aulete nota que *chover*](http://www.aulete.com.br/chover) pode, em sentido figurado, ser conjugado em todas as pessoas, e dá os seguintes exemplos:

> [...] *choveram pedras sobre os policiais cercados pelos manifestantes*
>
> [...] *Os convidados choveram arroz sobre os noivos*
>
> [...] *Bênçãos divinas choviam sobre a casa*

E na linguagem criativa abrem-se ainda outras possibilidade:
[image]

Comment: Acho que os convidados não podem *chover* arroz sobre os noivos, como as nuvens não podem chover chuva. A nuvem faz chover chuva, e os convidados fazem chover arroz. Tem um sujeito indeterminado, como no inglês "it rains". Nisso, discordo absolutamente com o Aulete. (Mas só nisso; com o resto concordo.)

Comment: @ANeves Também não gosto de os convidados choverem arroz, mas possivelmente há ou houve quem usasse *chover* dessa maneira. Agora, tu podes personificar a chuva: *eu sou a chuva, e chovo sobre os campos.* Parece-me que [este texto em galego](https://books.google.pt/books?id=CCsuEscvLd0C&pg=PA9&dq=%22chovo+sobre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjarZrOkbvMAhXK5xoKHQeWAaUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22chovo%20sobre%22&f=false) tem frases deste tipo. Ou podes falar com a chuva: *ó chuva, não achas que já choveste o suficiente? Descansa um pouco, ou vai chover para a Índia, onde todos anseiam pela tua chegada*.

Comment: Não, acho que a chuva não chove; é chovida. Como a nuvem não chove, faz chover. Nem mesmo «chover no molhado» consigo imaginar conjugado, porque eu conjugaria o verbo auxiliar: ***estás** a chover no molhado*.

Comment: @ANeves A linguagem, especialmente a não técnica, não se prende a essas lógicas. Procura no Googe Books, e encontras *chove/chovia uma chuva fina*, *chovo no molhado*, etc. E estes usos estão reconhecidos nos dicionários; também no Houaiss e no da Academia. Depois é uma questão de gosto. Para mim, muitas dessas construções resultam muito bem.

Comment: Música famosa; Chove chuva, chove sem parar.....